# Set P function property for jmeter API in Java

Tags: jmeter

I have a jmeter test that is already defined in the gui like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZDVY.png).

I am automating running this jmeter test from java, and I want to set `${__P(threads)}` from within the java code.

The relevant code is :

```
public List<String> runJmxTest(String jmxFile, String jtlFile) throws IOException {
    HashTree testPlanTree;
    List<String> resultSet = new ArrayList<>();
    // Initialize JMeter SaveService
    SaveService.loadProperties();
    JMeterVariables j = new JMeterVariables();
    j.put("threads", "10");
    // Load existing .jmx Test Plan
    File in = new File(jmeterHome.getPath() + "/bin/testPlans/" + jmxFile);
    try{
        testPlanTree = SaveService.loadTree(in);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e){
        resultSet.add("fail");
        resultSet.add(e.toString());
        return resultSet;
    }
    // set up custom result collector with summariser
    Summariser summer = new Summariser("caos-mbm summariser");
    collector = new myResultCollector(summer);
    if(jtlFile != null){
        if(!jtlFile.contains(".jtl")) {
            String jtlTmp = jtlFile.concat(".jtl");
            collector.setFilename(jmeterHome.getPath() + "/bin/testPlans/Output/" + jtlTmp);
        } else {
            collector.setFilename(jmeterHome.getPath() + "/bin/testPlans/Output/" + jtlFile);
        }
    }
    testPlanTree.add(testPlanTree.getArray()[0], collector);
    // Run Test Plan
    jm.configure(testPlanTree);
    jm.run();
    resultSet.add("success");
    resultSet.add(Double.toString(collector.getErrorPercent()));
    return resultSet;
}
```

I have tried setting the property through the props, adding it to the test plan tree, adding jmeterproperties to the jmetercontext. I can't get it to pick up the variable though.

Any advice would be appreciated. I have also looked through quite a few posts on here that seem similar but the solutions didn't work for me or the implementation was off.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong class, remove these lines:

```
JMeterVariables j = new JMeterVariables();
j.put("threads", "10");
```

and add the following instead:

```
org.apache.jmeter.util.JMeterUtils.setProperty("threads", "10");
```

You need to do this **after** loading the Test Plan and **before** running the test.

Also make sure to add [ApacheJMeter_functions.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.jmeter/ApacheJMeter_functions) to your project [CLASSPATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_(Java))

More information on running JMeter test using [JMeter API](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/index.html): [Five Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui)

Comment: this still isn't working for me. I have jmeter_functions in the pom file and I'm using maven to package  I have been running mvn clean install and everything runs correctly except for this part of the functionality. I tried to add it in after I run SaveService.loadTree(in) and after I run jm.configure(testPlanTree) but it still doesn't seem to pick up the property. Any advice

Comment: do you add it to the testPlanTree or is run by itself?

Comment: could you put up a small working example cause I have seen you reference this action in multiple questions and I can see the property set if I run JmeterUtil.getProperty("threads") but it still doesn't set it for the jmx file.